# how to write pine script for adx above 25?

Tags: pine-script

I have ema crossover strategy but i want my order to execute only when adx is above 25. I tried doing it in trading view using pinecript but it fails. So, i need pine script which execute only when adx is above 25.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a boolean variable on your condition like we do here with `cond`, which you can then use to plot conditionally or in your script's logic:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Directional Movement Index", shorttitle="DMI", format=format.price, precision=4)
len = input(17, minval=1, title="DI Length")
lensig = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
[_, _, adx] = dmi(len, lensig)
plot(adx, color=color.red, title="ADX")
hline(25)

cond = adx > 25
bgcolor(cond ? color.silver : na)
```

[image]